# How to remove a Domain Controller from a Forest to a Single Domain

Tags: domain, migration, transfer

I have a server which is a domain controller in a Forest. I want to remove that server from the forest and place it in its own domain so it becomes a single domain controller.

So say we have eight domain controllers in domain A I want to remove one domain controller from domain A and create domain B with the single domain controller on a completely separated network.

I've done a bit of searching and found tips on how to demote or transfer from one forest to another but this doesnt quite fit my scenario.

Any tips ?

Comment: You need to elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: So say we have eight domain controllers in domain A I want to remove one domain controller from domain A and create domain B with the single domain controller on a completely seperate network.

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly fundamental.

- Remove DC from domain using the normal procedure. DC becomes a member server in the domain.
- Remove member server from domain.
- Create new domain using the normal procedure.
- Job done.

I'd personally be considerably happier if "re-image server" was included as a middle step to ensure that any info/cruft on the server didn't live on when it took over its new role, but its not technically required.